# Using python with a specific version of OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, installation, virtualenv, opencv3.0

I am currently working on a project that add a new module to OpenCV 3.0 beta so I am trying to use my own compiled version with Python (just as a remark, the C++ version works).

Since I don't want to mess up with versions of OpenCV and Python already installed, I did not add to ldconfig my specific build/installation of OpenCV 3.0 beta and I would like to use it in a python virtualenv if possible.

So far I have setup the venv and since cv2 is not accessible in it, I update the `PYTHONPATH` to add the folder containing the `cv2.so` file (created with `sudo apt-get install python-opencv`). However, it is not the right version of opencv binding that are loaded :

```
$ python -c "import cv2; print cv2.__version__"
2.4.8
```

Have any idea on what I could do ?

EDIT (thanks @otibom):

My build seems to be the reason why I don't have the right `cv2.so` file. The results of cmake are :

```
--   Python 2:
--     Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python2.7 (ver 2.7.6)
--     Libraries:                   NO
--     numpy:                       /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.8.2)
--     packages path:               lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

Is there a way to correct that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compiling OpenCV 3.0 will create its own `cv2.so` file containing your new module, typically in your `opencv3-0-0-beta/build` directory. You need to add the OpenCV 3.0 build directory to `PYTHONPATH` instead of the one created by apt-get.

Comment: Thank you it helps that you confirm that. Actually I realized that that file is not created with my build. It might be because I think I have another issue (just realized it since I was not using OpenCV with Python before) : cmake does find the binaries of Python but not the libraries. I will update my question with that so it is clearer

Comment: Actually I solved the "finding library" problem and recompiled but I did not find that file in the build directory : `find -iname "cv2.so"` gave me nothing. Where exactly should it be ?

Comment: Nevermind, I forgot to compile in RELEASE mode, maybe that's why the file was not generated

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the "libraries not found" problem, I removed the file `CMakeCache.txt` and at the following cmake command it found python libraries. (but I have no idea why that happened)

Comment: I had the same problem under Windows (Python library keeps getting disabled); in the end, I had a look at the `CMakeLists.txt` of the Python module, and found out that enabling the option "Build_opencv_world" would disable the Python library.